# quarkus and hibernate mapping (field access)

Tags: quarkus

I moved an entity which worked in JEE wildfly to quarkus:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Item {

@Column(name = "archived")
private OffsetDateTime archived;

public boolean isArchived() {
    return archived != null;
}
}
```

After running in dev-mode, I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: 
In trying to locate getter for property [archived], 
Class [com.Item] 
defined both a `get` [public java.time.OffsetDateTime com.Item.getArchived()] 
and `is` [public boolean com.Item.isArchived()] variant
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.checkGetAndIsVariants(ReflectHelper.java:538)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.verifyNoGetVariantExists(ReflectHelper.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getGetterOrNull(ReflectHelper.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.findGetterMethod(ReflectHelper.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getterMethodOrNull(ReflectHelper.java:571)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessMixedImpl.getAccessType(PropertyAccessMixedImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessMixedImpl.<init>(PropertyAccessMixedImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessEnhancedImpl.<init>(PropertyAccessEnhancedImpl.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessStrategyEnhancedImpl.buildPropertyAccess(PropertyAccessStrategyEnhancedImpl.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:59)
    ... 35 more
```

I understand the error but I dont know why does this hibernate mapping work in wildfly and not in quarkus? As I declared **jpa field access** instead of **jpa property access**, hibernate should see the `isArchived()` automatically as `transient`.

Or does quarkus compiles all these field-injections to property-injections?

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus generates a getter for the `archived` field. 
Here Hibernate complains that you have two accessors for the `archived` field: `isArchived()` and `getArchived()`.

This is an Hibernate issue/limitation, nothing specific to Quarkus.

I think the best is to rename your `isArchived()` method as Hibernate don't know which method to use to retrieve the value of the `archived`field. And if you add `@Transient` to your `isArchived()` method it could (depending on wich method it get first) handle your field as transient.

Comment: I used this mapping described above in JEE environment (also hibernate) and it had always worked without complains..after moving this entity to quarkus..I get this complain (with the **SAME** hibernate version). Does quarkus use **byte code enhancements** or jpa **property access** even if I declard my mappings by **jpa field access"**? My entity declared **jpa field access"**, that means: hibernate should **not** consider my properties. But in quarkus it does. Why?

Comment: As I said, Quarkus generates getters and setters for Hibernate. You also have Lombok that generates them I think right ? The mix of all of them generates the issue on Hibernate. If you really think it is an issue on Quarkus side please open an issue here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues

Comment: "Quarkus generates getters and setters for Hibernate". I dont think so, because I do not use Panache with public fields. And as I said before, the SAME mappings worked in JEE environment. I use field access and not property access..